# Wrong push to remote

Tags: git

This is my situation.

I have realized that my local branch `master` has the wrong name, it should be called `develop` like the remote branch.

I need to push to the `develop` remote branch.

Unfortunately I did `commit` and `git push origin develop` and now

- the data on the remote do not contain my commit;
- now if I do `git status` I get `On branch master nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Please how do I solve this situation and push my last commit to the correct remote branch (`develop`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just check out `develop`, merge `master` into it, and push `develop`.

You could also `cherry-pick` just the one commit from `master` into `develop`, then push.

```
git checkout develop    
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
git push origin develop
```

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick